# How to store the resolved value of a promise inside a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I am using NodeJs v10.19.0 I already read tons of `async/await` documentations and tutorials but still can't get this right.

I constantly make a get request to API that give me some JSON data I would like to have that data available at any time inside a  variable

**How do I do that?**

So far I've tried as the example below shows but with no success

Thank you for your consideration

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const myURL =  '{A_GET_URL_THAT_RETURNS_A_JSON}';
const options = {uri:myURL, json: true};

const data = ( async ()=>{
    try{
       return await rp(options)
    }catch (e) {
        console.log('error \n' + e.stack);
    }
})();

console.log(data);  // this gets me: "Promise { <pending> }"  instead of the json data
```

I tried several syntaxes and still can't make it work nor realize where is my flaw

Why I cannot get the resolved value for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `async` function ALWAYS returns a promise.  That's why `data` in your case is a promise.  That is expected.

The `return` value inside an `async` function becomes the resolved value of that promise that it returns.  So, the resolved value of the promise you get will be the value you want.

When calling an `async` function, you will need to use `.then()` or `await` to get the value from the returned promise.

```
const promise = ( async ()=>{
    try{
       return await rp(options)
    }catch (e) {
        console.log('error \n' + e.stack);
    }
})();

promise.then(val => {
    console.log(val);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

`await` is only really useful INSIDE the async function where it is used.  When an `async` function is executing, at the point it hits the first `await`, then the function immediately returns a pending promise and the caller immediately gets that promise.  Further execution of the function body is suspended until the promise that you are awaiting resolves.  When that promise resolves and the event loop is free, then the function will resume executing.  When, the function eventually returns, the promise that it already returned will be given a resolved value from whatever your code specifies as a return value.

In addition, `return await fn()` does nothing useful.  It generates the same result as just `return fn()`.  Either way the function has already returned a promise and what you specify with `return` will become the resolved value of the promise that has already been returned.  If you specify a promise, then it's resolved value will be the value.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. It clarifies a a lot but I am still don't know how to make the  return value accessible inside a variable which is my main goal. I realized my question wast no clear enough so I just edited it a bit. 

Thanks again

Comment: @OscarOrtizGarcía - I repeat.  You get access to the return value of an `async` function ONLY by using `.then()` or `await` on the returned promise.  Those are your choices.  You cannot directly assign the return value into a variable - because when you do that, all you will get is the promise.  A function cannot directly return the result of an asynchronous operation in Javascript because the function returns BEFORE the asynchronous result is available.  You need to adapt your code design to how asynchronous operations work in Javascript.